# Federated Learning for Image Classification in colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I'm new in Federated learning, I tried to implement the code of FL for Image Classification, but I can't understand this line

I am confused in some detail parts. I am trying to build a sequential model in Keras, but when I train the model, I am getting this error, How may I fix it?

please guide me
thank you.

```
iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-0fdb188570d0> in <module>()
----> 1 iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)

TypeError: build_federated_averaging_process() missing 1 required positional argument: 'client_optimizer_fn'
```

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/federated/blob/v0.12.0/docs/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=sk6mjOfycX5N

Answer (score 3):

This is an error from python about the function call, see [this answer and question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65191216/14692) for a similar scenario.

The API documentation for [`tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/build_federated_averaging_process) indicates that two arguments are required: a `model_fn` argument and a `client_optimizer_fn`.

From the code, it looks like only the first argument is specified. The colab notebook link above points to an older version of TFF (`0.12.0`, most recent is `0.19.0`). The old version of the colab notebook is not guaranteed with newer versions of the PIP package.

In the [newer colab notebook version](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/federated/blob/v0.19.0/docs/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=FK3c8_leS9_t) the call has been updated to match the current API and includes additional parameters:

```py
iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fn,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.02),
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0))
```